# Private YouTube video does not appear on channel, even when shared

Tags: youtube, sharing, youtube-channel

I uploaded a YouTube video using account A, set it to private, and shared it with account B. Now B can view the video using a direct link.

When I visit account A's channel using account A, the video appears in the videos tab.

When I visit account A's channel using account B, the video does not appear. Can I make it visible?

Answer (score 0):

An acceptable workaround is to add the private video to a public playlist.